# Why is my code not recognizing all parts of my list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nltk, urllib

I have created a list of websites and my goal is to find the most frequently used words (excluding the common ones such as the, as, are, and etc.) across all of these sites. I set this up to the best of my abilities but I am realizing that my function is only providing the words to the first website to my list. I created a loop function but I believe I may have messed something up and am looking for the fix.

My current code is:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
import urllib.request

list1 = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney+", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Video",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulu", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunchyroll",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESPN%2B", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HBO_Max", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramount%2B", 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBS", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peacock_(streaming_service)", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery%2B", 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showtime_(TV_network)", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epix", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starz", 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorn_TV", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BritBox", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kocowa", 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantelion_Films", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spuul"]

freq = [ ]

for i in list1:
    response =  urllib.request.urlopen(i)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    text = soup.get_text(strip = True)
    tokens = [t for t in text.split()]
    sr= stopwords.words('english')
    clean_tokens = tokens[:]

    for token in tokens:    
        if token in stopwords.words('english'):            
            clean_tokens.remove(token)

    freq = nltk.FreqDist(clean_tokens)
    freq1 = freq.most_common(20)
    freq[i] = pd.DataFrame(freq.items(), columns=['word', 'frequency'])
    freq1
    print("This is for the website: ", i, "\n", freq1)
```

The output for `freq1` is giving me the most popular 20 words only for the first website, and I am looking for the most popular words across all websites.

Comment: You assign an empty list to `freq` before your loop, then you clobber it by assigning `freq = nltk.FreqDist(clean_tokens)` inside your loop.

Comment: @khelwood If it is not a bother could you provide the edited code for me? I am still intermediate, and I did apply your change but something is still up with it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirements or your code enough to rewrite it for you.

Comment: use a different name for the list `freq` anyway, you seem to be using it for 2 separate things, and instead of `freq[i]` to add to a list you should do `freq.append()`

Comment: @RolvApneseth Thank you for the response :) Do you mind providing a more clear example as many things go over my head?

Comment: But I can't run your code and I don't know what it's meant to do

Answer (score 0):

program is overwriting the list items in the line:
freq1 = freq.most_common(20)

As python gives a nice way to append the list, refer (2).
sorry, edited your code, pls refer line and comment at (1),(2) and (3)

```
freq = [ ]
freq_list=[] # added new structure for list, as want to avoid conflict with your variables --(1)
for i in list1:
    response =  urllib.request.urlopen(i)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
    text = soup.get_text(strip = True)
    tokens = [t for t in text.split()]
    sr= stopwords.words('english')
    clean_tokens = tokens[:]

    for token in tokens:    
        if token in stopwords.words('english'):            
            clean_tokens.remove(token)

    freq = nltk.FreqDist(clean_tokens)
    freq1 = freq.most_common(20)
    freq_list=freq_list + freq1 # python way to add list items --(2)
    freq[i] = pd.DataFrame(freq.items(), columns=['word', 'frequency'])
    #freq1
    print("This is for the website: ", i, "\n", freq1)
df=pd.DataFrame(freq_list, columns=['word', 'frequency']) # build the dataframe (3)
df.shape
```